# Sencha Touch - how to display up to date content in Nested List?

Tags: sencha-touch, refresh, nested-lists

So let's say in Sencha Touch, I created a Nested List like so

```
var NestedList = createList(jsonDataObject,'leftNavigation','list','bookmark-icon');
function createList( data , id , cls, iconCls)
{
    var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
        model: 'ListItem',
        root: data,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            reader: {
            type: 'tree',
            root: 'items'
            }
        }
    });

    var leftNav = new Ext.NestedList({
        //    cardSwitchAnimation: false,
        dock: 'left',
        id: id,
        cls: 'card '+cls,
        useTitleAsBackText: true,
        title: data.text ,
        iconCls: iconCls,
        displayField: 'text',
        width: '350',
        store: store});
}
```

After a while, the contents of `jsonDataObject` will change (either periodically via a `setInterval()` call or because of user interaction).  I may also need to submit an entirely new `jsonDataObject` to the `NestedList` store. So my questions are:

a) How do I get the `NestedList` to refresh and display a new UI with the new data?

b) Is my implementation of `createList()` the most appropriate way to create a `Nestlisted`?  Or is there a better way for my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because no one answered my question in time, I used a work around.

I kept the code as is in the question.  The nested list is used by a container panel.  So what I did was remove the old nestedlist from the container panel, destroy it, then create a new nestedlist, and insert it back to container panel.  As an example:

```
// my old nestedlist was item 1 of the container, where container is Ext.TabPanel()
// you can re-use this strategy with any component in the container.items.items array
var oldnestedlist = container.items.items[1]; 
container.remove(oldnestedlist);
oldnestedlist.destroy();

// create the new nestedlist
var NestedList = createList(jsonDataObject,'leftNavigation','list','bookmark-icon');
container.insert(1,NestedList);
// After you insert the NestedList, the screen hasn't been redrawn yet,
// so i force the user to go back to screen if container.items.items[0] via
// setActiveItem(0).  You can choose the screen in any other
// container.items.items array
container.setActiveItem(0);

// Next time someone presses the tab for containers.items.items[1], the screen will automatically redraw
```